# php - multiple requests with curl (NOT 'multi-threaded')

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

If i want to do multiple things (that require cookies) with curl, for example:

1. login to (my own) blog
2. then automatically submit a blog post

do I do this in one curl instance before curl close or do i close first session and then start second one for second task? (Sorry if it's dumb question but i can't quite get it. Generally all examples on the net i find about curl are doing only one thing... this doesn't help me with understanding it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking:

1. Initialize curl. ([`curl_init`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php), or [`curl_multi_init`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php))
2. Do thing(s). (in multiple [`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) calls if needed, or [`curl_multi_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php))
3. Close curl. ([`curl_close`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php) or [`curl_multi_close`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-close.php))

So yes, all in one session.

Comment: Ok... so let's say i'm using code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728274/php-curl-post-to-login-to-wordpress to login into my blog... how do i add post submitting? Should I add my code after curl exec but before curl close? Can I just add different curl_setopt parameters (url, referrer, etc) and exec it again with these parameters? Or what i'm talking is total nonsense? ;)

Comment: @Phil - yep, add different parameters, set different operations, call curl_exec, and do the same again, and call curl_close when you're *done* done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes open and close each curl object before moving to the next.