# how to login to another site via PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to find out how to login to another site via PHP... I don't know the proper term for it, but basically, I want a user to be able to enter their login information for another website on mine, and interact with it through mine.Is there any tutorial?
thanks

Comment: You need to use Curl - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Most sites not welcome such a behavior. what site you're trying to log in?

Comment: ISP site http://10.240.43.216 .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are few ways to do the job (actually, you just need to send POST data to the other site).

You can use :

- curl (example: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl),
- stream context (example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php),
- or directly with sockets (example: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm).

Answer (score 2):

curl will do that [PHP, cURL post to login to WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728274/php-curl-post-to-login-to-wordpress)

but you will need that installed on the server which is sometimes not an option. There is however loads of scripts that can do the same thing as curl without the curl libs installed, eg: cakephp's HttpSocket class

Answer (score 0):

as already stated, Curl will do that.
But you can also check out this PHP Class that makes everything easier and gives you a lot of automation out of the Box
Including Prefilling of CSRF Token, finding of all input fields, retrieving of details from the designated site. etc
the class can be found Here. [Crawl Engine](https://github.com/Okerefe/CrawlEngine/)