# How to get some part of html using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have html page with structure like this

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">
      <div id="4">
        <div id="5">   
          <div id="photo">    
            <a id="photo" href="link">
              <img width="200" src="http://site.com/photo.jpg"> 
            </a> 
          </div>
          <div id="info"></div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

I need to get img url (http://site.com/...)

my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html('http://site.com/123');


// find all div tags with id=gbar
foreach($html->find('img[width="200"]') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

but it doesn't work for this site.
May be there is another way to get image url

Comment: you cannot have two elements having same id. please correct that first.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha - semantically true but I don't think simple-html-dom cares as it parses a flat file and will simply return the first occurrence.

Comment: OP: What site? Are you sure the HTML your script is being served is the same as the HTML you are being served. ie.  `file_get_html` (i think) uses the native `files_get_contents` which in turn sends a raw request with no headers - the likes of Facebook for example wont give you the content you are expecting without the user-agent being specified.  Can you `echo $html` and double check that this is the structure you are expecting.

Comment: for wordpress site pages it works correct

Comment: page is like http://vk.com/durov

Comment: There is no error in above code!!! but it may chance to have some problem to grab data though file_get_content() or url provide some data which is not in form of HTML!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected the site serves different content based on the User-Agent, to get the HTML that you are expecting you need let the server know you want the "for browsers" version.  For example you could remove this line:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://vk.com/durov');
```

... and replace it with something like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
  'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'
)));
$html = str_get_html( file_get_contents('http://vk.com/durov', false, $context) );
```

I should note that the practice of spoofing the User-Agent is generally frowned upon and you should perhaps run this to see if the information contained suits your needs:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/plain');
  echo file_get_contents('http://siteurl.com');
```

which will show the source code that the site wants bots to see - for the site in question this is a lightweight version of the page - which from your point of view takes less time to process.

Comment: @user2054164 definitely works mate - I've just run [this](http://pastebin.com/2p6qAcBQ) which printed a single line `http://cs7003.vk.me/v7003685/1ddd/jZ8LZcwYN20.jpg` \[[link](http://cs7003.vk.me/v7003685/1ddd/jZ8LZcwYN20.jpg)\]

Comment: you are right I just get lightweight page without tags that I need, thats why I get empty result. Is it way to get the desired result?

Comment: but if I need to be logged to see user profile, it return empty result, is it possible to add authorization in this code

Comment: It's certainly possible - You're better off using cURL to fetch pages with the necessary post requests and store cookie data etc.  That is another question in itself though - there are plenty of StackOveflow examples - [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873783/how-to-login-to-another-site-via-php) - on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be `$html->find('img[width=200]')` without extra quotes around `200`.

Comment: @user2054164 Your example works fine for me even with quotes around `200`.  Can you insert `print_r ($html)` right after `$html = file_get_html('http://site.com/123');` and post here what does it print?

Comment: empty, site is the main page of vk.com user like vk.com/durov

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to find it, for example:

```
<?php 
$string = '
<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">
      <div id="4">
        <div id="5">   
          <div id="photo">    
            <a id="photo" href="link">
              <img width="200" src="http://site.com/photo.jpg"> 
            </a> 
          </div>
          <div id="info"></div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> ';

$pattern = '/http[^""]+/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://site.com/photo.jpg
)
```

Comment: how to change $string to page url