# cURL post to login to kicktipp.de

Tags: php, curl

I want to remote login to www.kicktipp.de and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728274/php-curl-post-to-login-to-wordpress) source code. First I successfully tried it out for a login page from another webpage of mine, but when I try to login to kicktipp.de it fails.
When I use this line:

```
$postdata = "kennung=" . $myusername . "&passwort=" . $mypassword . "&submitbutton=1";
```

only my username is inserted, but not the password. Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: In the page-source code of kicktipp.de it is called "passwort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify these details:

1. The POST should be maked to http://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/loginaction.
2. The hidden-value *charset* is empty and should be included.
3. The hidden-value kt_page with "/profil/loginaction" should be included.
4. The value of the button "submitbutton" is "Anmelden".

I think one of this things should be the solution.

---

Folgende Dinge bitte beachten:

1. Der POST muss an http://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/loginaction erfolgen.
2. Das hidden-value *charset* sollte auch leer übergeben werden.
3. Das hidden-value kt_page "/profil/loginaction" sollte übergeben werden.
4. Eventuell auch noch beim submitbutton "Anmelden" übergeben.

Ich denke, an einer Sache davon wird es liegen.

Comment: edit: thank you, it works! But I had to add `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "kennung=" . $username . ";passwort=" . $password);`

Comment: With this, you set a cookie ;-) Then you probably does not need to login dedicated.

Comment: Well, goal is to get the html-content of `http://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/meinetipprunden` from the user who logged in. So what would be the simplest solution?

Comment: You can try to get the profile without logging in before but simply setting the cookie value.